# Javascript - float value from an HTML input in table cell

Tags: javascript, cell, parsefloat

It's part of the larger task. Why is the problem `Nan` and how to solve it? The table is added together elements from several pools `<input>` which elemenatymi table. All code is summed up in the table of size `k / d`.

Why is the problem Nan and how to solve it?

```js
function licz(tableID){
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 var k, d, s=0, temp;
 var i = table.rows.length;
      for(k=1; k<=i; k++){
          for(d=0; d<2; d++){
temp = parseFloat(document.getElementById(tableID).rows[k].cells[d].innerHTML);
alert(temp);
s=s+temp;
          }
document.getElementById(tableID).rows[k].cells[d].innerHTML = s;
              
     } 
}
```

```html
<form name="roz" action="">
<table id="tyg" class="product_values" style="width: 20%" border=1>
<tr>
  <td> Pon </td>
  <td>  Wt </td>
  <td> Sum </td>
</tr><tr>
<td> <input type="number" name="inp_a" ></td>
  <td> 4 </td> 
  <td></td>        
</table>
</form>
<button onclick="licz('tyg')">go</button>
```

Comment: Hello everyone
It's part of the larger task. Why is the problem Nan and how to solve it?

The table is added together elements from several pools <input> which elemenatymi table.

All code is summed up in the table of size k / d.

Why is the problem Nan and how to solve it?

Comment: because you're trying to parse a string, "<input type="number" name="inp_a" />", hence you got the NaN which stand for Not a number.

Comment: Yes, you need to access the `value` property for an input field.

Answer (score 1):

This is not right way for getting value from child elements you should do something like this :

JavaScript:

```
  function licz(tableID){
     var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
               var k, d, temp;
               var i = table.rows.length;

               for (k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
                   for (d = 0; d < 2; d++) {
                       if (d == 0) {
                           temp = parseFloat(document.getElementById(tableID).rows[k].cells[d].childNodes[1].value);
                       }
                       if (d == 1) {
                           temp = temp + parseFloat(document.getElementById(tableID).rows[k].cells[d].innerHTML);
                       }
                   }
                   document.getElementById(tableID).rows[k].cells[d].innerHTML = temp;
                   document.getElementById('num').v
               }
           }
```

HTML:

```
        <table id="tyg" class="product_values" style="width: 20%" border=1>
        <tr>
            <td> Pon </td>
            <td>  Wt </td>
            <td> Sum </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input id = 'num' type="number" name="inp_a" ></td>
            <td> 4 </td> 
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

well... it's a good question. You should read DOM for knowing more about this.